# 「娘と祖父の記憶とを連れて」の「とを」はどう言う意味

Tags: grammar, literature

「とを」はどういう意味でしょうか。タイポですか？

In this short story, the narrator is describing the moment he first fell in love, and how it helped him remember why he has the habit of staring at people’s faces (the reason being he developed that habit while living with his blind grandfather, hence the reference to 祖父の記憶). The phrase comes from the last sentence of the story.

Context: 私は笑った。娘に親しみが急に加わったような気がした。娘と祖父の記憶とを連れて、砂浜の日向へ出てみたくなった。
Source: 「日向」（p26; 川端康成の掌の小説；新潮文庫）

Comment: I might be wrong but I think this と means "and." The final と is usually optional and can be omitted. According to DoBJG: 1. *と is used to list things exhaustively. **The final と is usually omitted**, but the others are not. Thus, "A, B, C and D" is usually expressed as "AとBとCとD."*

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems you are in fact correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jimmy Yang commented, the second と can be omitted (and is usually omitted), and the phrase can be written as

> .. 娘と祖父の記憶を連れて、..

However, in this particular case, there is a slight chance that a reader would parse the sentence without the second と,

> 娘と祖父の記憶を連れて、砂浜の日向へ出てみたくなった。

down to the structure

- 娘と（いっしょに、）A してみたくなった。

  - where A is
    祖父の記憶を連れて、砂浜の日向へ出る。

which could be interpreted as

> 娘と私がともに祖父の記憶を思い返している状態で、いっしょに砂浜の日向へ出てみたくなった。

I guess that the preceding context would exclude this possibility (e.g., the daughter and the narrator must share the same memory of the grand father for this interpretation to be valid), but in any way the original text clearly expresses that 娘 and 祖父の記憶 are two parallel objects that the narrator wants to bring with him or her to the sunny beach.

I haven't read the source text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had always told that と went between the nouns being conjoined, so I kept searching for information on とを. 恥ずかしいです。

Comment: That's not anything to be 恥ずかしい. I do the same when I learn a foreign language myself. I'm glad you asked a question.